# In Freeform, where is the 'from' email address set?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using freeform for a simple contact form. Notification emails are being sent when the form is submitted, but they are coming from my gmail.com email address, and I would like them to come from my info@mydomainname.com address. Where can I set the email address that the form submission notification emails originate from?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you do not have any Email Notification templates created, Freeform will use its internal default one, which grabs the main Email address in your EE Email Configuration.

You really should create a new Email Notification template (in "Notifications" page of Freeform control panel area), where you can customize the email notification and set the from name/email address, etc. Then just be sure to specify this new notification template in either your Form's settings or in your EE template with the applicable parameter.